# How to bring the label of toggle buttons to the left

Tags: html, css

I have a switch toggle button for an HTML  page

```
    <div>
       <label class="switch" style="margin-left:14em;">
            <h5>Profile</h5>
            <input id="profile-toggle" checked type="checkbox">
            <span class="slider round"></span>
      </label>
    </div>
```

It shows on the page like this:

[image]

I am trying to bring the label to the left side, similar to this:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea on how can I do this?

## EDIT Toggle CSS

```
/* The switch - the box around the slider */
.switch {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 60px;
 height: 34px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {display:none;}

/* The slider */
.slider {
 position: absolute;
 cursor: pointer;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 background-color: #e61610;
 -webkit-transition: .4s;
 transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
 position: absolute;
 content: "";
 height: 26px;
 width: 26px;
 left: 4px;
 bottom: 4px;
 background-color: white;
 -webkit-transition: .4s;
 transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
background-color: #29b6f6;
}

input:focus + .slider {
 box-shadow: 0 0 1px #29b6f6;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
 -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
-ms-transform: translateX(26px);
transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
 border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
border-radius: 50%;
}
```

## PS

The toggle switch works fine, my problem is to bring the label to the left side, in front of the button.

Comment: Your code does not reveal anything about how the toggle works. Styles? Frameworks?

Comment: Can you post the code for the first output?

Comment: can you show us your css

Comment: I am using only css and html.

Comment: Change switch width

Comment: You can alter the position of h5. https://jsfiddle.net/8x4y0rub/

Comment: @A.Meshu I don't think that will alter the position of the label text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this bunch of css code and you are all good.

```
.switch h5 {
  position: absolute;
  left: -14rem;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0.75rem;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
/* The switch - the box around the slider */

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 28px;
  margin-left:14em;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */

.switch input {
  display: none;
}

/* The slider */

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: green;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 1px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: green;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #29b6f6;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(2px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.switch h5 {
  position: relative;
  left: -200px;
  top: -50%;
  width: 175px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label class="switch">
                <h5>Do you want to check</h5>
                <input id="profile-toggle" checked type="checkbox">
                <span class="slider round"></span>
          </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label class="switch">
                <h5>Check Grammar and Spelling on Stackoverflow.com</h5>
                <input id="profile-toggle" checked type="checkbox">
                <span class="slider round"></span>
          </label>
</div>
```